# Variable @DBName en Procedimiento Almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente script que ya funciona correctamente. Sirve para insertar los usuarios de un sistema, dentro de la tabla de usuarios de otro sistema. Les dejo el Script:

```
INSERT INTO Usuarios.Usuario (PrimerNombre, SegundoNombre, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido,
Usuario, Llave, CorreoElectronico, Activo, ID_Rol)
SELECT
T0.Firstname AS PrimerNombre, NULL AS SegundoNombre, T0.Lastname AS PrimerApellido,
NULL AS SegundoApellido, T0.LoginName AS Usuario, 
ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('6aK4yxRqoyHWcEAOtp3W', 'T0.Password') AS Llave, 
NULL AS CorreoElectronico, 1 AS Activo,
CASE T2.Name WHEN 'Security Officer' THEN 1 WHEN 'FD Clerk' THEN 2 
WHEN 'RM Division Manager' THEN 4 WHEN 'RM General Manager' THEN 4 END AS ID_Rol
FROM 
KawilalPMS.dbo.seUser AS T0 LEFT JOIN
KawilalPMS.dbo.seUserTemplates AS T1 ON T0.Id_UserTemplates = T1.ID_UserTemplates LEFT JOIN
KawilalPMS.dbo.prCode AS T2 ON T1.ID_UserTemplates = T2.ID_Code
WHERE 
T0.IsActif = 1 AND 
T2.NAME IN ('Security Officer', 'FD Clerk', 'RM Division Manager', 'RM General Manager')
```

Lo que necesito es reemplazar el nombre de la base de datos KawilalPMS ya que cada cliente tiene un nombre de base de datos distinto, según el nombre de la propiedad, pero no sé como hacer para declarar esta variable, ustedes me podrían orientar un poco?

Comment: Para poder cambiar el nombre de la base de datos de las tablas en función de algo, tendrás que utilizar un Sql dinámico. De lo que muestras no se entiende lo que significa "Según el nombre de la propiedad"

Comment: Según el nombre de la propiedad es el nombre del negocio, ya que trabajamos para varios negocios, en este caso, el ejemplo del código el nombre de la base de datos es KawilalPMS, en otra ocasión puede que sea Cliente1PMS o Cliente2PMS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la pregunta has puesto stored-Procedure y te expongo el resultado en uno. El parámetro que recibe el mismo es el nombre del negocio.

Al no tener un escenario completo, con unos datos y poder probar la query, esta se ha montado al vuelo, por lo cual puede contener algún tipo de error de sintaxis, que observarás al ejecutar el mismo.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es envolver tú query en una variable de tipo cadena "nvarchar", y lanzar la ejecución de este y te pintará en la ventana de resultados la query, que tiene que ser idéntica a la que has planteado.

```
Create procedure dbo.queryDinamica (@nombreNegocio nvarchar(128))
As
Begin

    --Set @nombreNegocio = N'kawilalpms';
    
    Declare @query nvarchar(max);
    Set @query = N'
    Insert Into usuarios.usuario(primernombre
                               , segundonombre
                               , primerapellido
                               , segundoapellido
                               , usuario
                               , llave
                               , correoelectronico
                               , activo
                               , id_rol)
    Select t0.firstname As primernombre
         , Null As segundonombre
         , t0.lastname As primerapellido
         , Null As segundoapellido
         , t0.loginname As usuario
         , EncryptByPassPhrase(''6aK4yxRqoyHWcEAOtp3W'', ''T0.Password'') As llave
         , Null As correoelectronico
         , 1 As activo
         , Case t2.name
               When ''Security Officer'' Then 1
               When ''FD Clerk'' Then 2
               When ''RM Division Manager'' Then 4
               When ''RM General Manager'' Then 4
           End As id_rol
           From '+@nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.seuser As t0
                Left Join '+ @nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.seusertemplates As t1 On t0.id_usertemplates = t1.id_usertemplates
                Left Join '+ @nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.prcode As t2 On t1.id_usertemplates = t2.id_code
           Where t0.isactif = 1 And t2.name In(''Security Officer'', ''FD Clerk'', ''RM Division Manager'', ''RM General Manager'');';

Print @query;   
--  Exec sp_executeSql @query;

End;
```

Por tanto:

```
exec dbo.queryDinamica N'KawilalPMS';
```

[image: Retorno]

El resultado el el mismo. Ahora solo restaría, quitar los guiones de la linea --Exec sp_executeSql @query para que se ejecute a la invocación del procedure la sentencia.

```
Alter procedure dbo.queryDinamica (@nombreNegocio nvarchar(128))
As
Begin

    --Set @nombreNegocio = N'kawilalpms';
    
    Declare @query nvarchar(max);
    Set @query = N'
    Insert Into usuarios.usuario(primernombre
                               , segundonombre
                               , primerapellido
                               , segundoapellido
                               , usuario
                               , llave
                               , correoelectronico
                               , activo
                               , id_rol)
    Select t0.firstname As primernombre
         , Null As segundonombre
         , t0.lastname As primerapellido
         , Null As segundoapellido
         , t0.loginname As usuario
         , EncryptByPassPhrase(''6aK4yxRqoyHWcEAOtp3W'', ''T0.Password'') As llave
         , Null As correoelectronico
         , 1 As activo
         , Case t2.name
               When ''Security Officer'' Then 1
               When ''FD Clerk'' Then 2
               When ''RM Division Manager'' Then 4
               When ''RM General Manager'' Then 4
           End As id_rol
           From '+@nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.seuser As t0
                Left Join '+ @nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.seusertemplates As t1 On t0.id_usertemplates = t1.id_usertemplates
                Left Join '+ @nombreNegocio + N'.dbo.prcode As t2 On t1.id_usertemplates = t2.id_code
           Where t0.isactif = 1 And t2.name In(''Security Officer'', ''FD Clerk'', ''RM Division Manager'', ''RM General Manager'');';
    
    Exec sp_executeSql @query;

End;
go
```

Como puedes ver, los apóstrofes, los tienes que doblar, para su correcta ejecución.

Exec sp_executeSql, admite una lista de parámetros, y es muy robusto y poderoso, y nos sirve para evitar la ***inyección de Sql***, cosa que hay que tienes que tener muy en cuenta. Ojo, que por usarlo, no se evita, tienes que tenerlo en cuenta en función de cual sea el escenario donde vayas a utilizarlo, como se alimentan los parámetros etc.

[exec sp_executeSql con parámetros](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)

[Inyección de código SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Aunque sea tarde quería darte las gracias, esta ha sido una de las mejores explicaciones que me he encontrado en esta comunidad y me ayudó no solo con este procedimiento sino también a entender de una vez por todas el SQL Dinámico. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @GioGómez De nada. Nunca es tarde para encontrar personas a las que el apoyo les ayuda. No obstante con marcar la respuesta como aceptada, es suficiente, ya que es la forma predeterminada en esta comunidad.